# How can I access the Clipboard?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to access the Clipboard in Flutter, but I encounter the following error:

> Class or object does not exist.

Am I missing an import?

I tried the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Clipboard.setData();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer Updated :**

Import :

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

And implement this :

```
IconButton(
    icon: Icon(
        Icons.content_copy,
        color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    onPressed: () {
        Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: "your text"));
    }
),
```

Comment: No need for "new" there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `flutter/services.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Now, you can access [`Clipboard.setData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/Clipboard/setData.html).